# React Router 4 - location.key is not available in props of <Match> children

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I use the `location.key` in my child components.

The key is by default 6 characters long. For instances it looks like this:

```
Object { pathname: "/one", search: "", hash: "", query: null, key: "rjtd5t" }
```

However the `location` property received by children of `<Match>` looks like this:

```
Object { params: Object, isExact: true, pathname: "/one", location: Object, pattern: "/one/:pid?" }

location: Object { pathname: "/one", search: "", hash: "", query: null, state: null }
```

In this `location` object we see `state` but its null, I expcted it to be value of the `key`. Does anyone know if react router v4 plans to get this? Or if there is a way to get it in the props? I know of course I can get this key by going `const history = createBrowserHistory(); let cur_key = history.location.key` however this is may not match up with the props (due to animation timing etc), that's why I was hoping to get it from prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug and it was fixed. AT the time of this solution alpha6 is out, it was fixed in alpha7. You can see the details in this issue topic on the official repo - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4336#issuecomment-273479938